# How to change a button icon color of a child element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a Modal.Header with a closeButton (which is white by default) and I want to change its color to black.

The code for the component is:

```
const inlineStyles = {
      header: {
        padding: '18px',
        margin: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#F2F3F4',
      },
```

`<Modal.Header style={inlineStyles.header} closeButton >`

The HTML of the rendered X-button looks like:
`<button type="button" aria-label="Close" class="close237497"></button>`

[image: I want to make the circled X button on the right "black"]

Comment: you can pass the props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow with [this](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/d819e86620f94e973f3c4df05ce76c94043e95fc/src/ModalHeader.js#L8) file of `React-Bootstrap`. When you pass a `closeButton prop` into `ModalHeader`, the button will has class is `close`.

So, you can override that class like this:

```
// create a file to override CSS bootstrap (override.css)
// override style of closeButton ModalHeader
.close {
   color: #fc0303 !important // red
   // orther style
}
```

```
import ModalHeader from 'react-bootstrap/ModalHeader';
import "./override.css";


// use ModalHeader
<ModalHeader closeButton />
```

Comment: My code is in a .js file, so I placed the override code in a separate .css file. It did not work. Am I missing out anything?

Comment: No luck yet! The exact structure is
`<div class = modal-header>
::before
<button class = "close-wdwewdddgtht" >

Comment: This definitely would work, but did not in my case because the icon I was dealing with was a picture (.png) and sitting in another project where I did not dig into.

Answer (score 0):

Use the style prop in your `Modal.Header` to set style in `button` like this

```
<button type="button" aria-label="Close" style={this.props.style}></button>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve that through my code. But, I did try editing the rendered HTML
`<button type="button" class="close _3DvpxcY5HLBjkdHQNUwI2m" aria-label="Close" style="color:black"></button>`
But, no luck!

Comment: you need `color:black !important`, since `class=close_etc` will also have color property.